# chrome.history.search() -> undefined [chrome extension]

Tags: function, search, google-chrome

I am new and quite a beginner but i tried to write an extension that requires to search an url in the history of chrome. I have been looking for parts of code here and google but still failing...

My manifest seems correct:

```
    "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "history"
    ],
```

But the javascript part is more confusing:

```
var histories = [];

chrome.history.search({text:'', maxResults:0, startTime: 0}, function(historyItems){
for(var h in historyItems){
    histories.push({'id':h.id, 'url':h.url});
    }
});
console.log(histories.length + ' histories');

alert(histories.length);
```

The alert shows 0. The Asynchronous problem is not supposed to be a problem here.
Thank you fr your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `maxResults` set to `0`, so no results will be returned.

Try setting `maxResults` to a positive integer, like `100`, or omit `maxResults` entirely to return all matching history items.

You will also want to move your `alert()` and `console.log()` functions to be within `chrome.history.search`'s callback function, otherwise `histories.length` will be `0` when the functions are called.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems h.url is undefined but it works otherwise

Comment: Ah, change `h.id` to `historyItems[h].id`, and `h.url` to `historyItems[h].url` :)

Comment: As of 2018, omitting `maxResults` only returns 100 results. Including it with a value of `0` retrieves way more. Not sure if that's ALL results or not.